# Rails Active Record - How to ordering by multiple fields conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following query:

`users.order("encounters.created #{order}")`

But if the "created" field is null, I want to sort using a different field with same data type (in this scenario, DateTime), something like this:

`user.order("encounters.created or encounter.start #{order}")`

which surely does not works.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: https://www.thd.codes/posts/how-to-write-order-by-case-query-with-arel/

Comment: You can try this: users.order("COALESCE(encounters.created, encounter.start) #{order}")

Answer (score 0):

After help from max and some research, found a solution:

```
order_statement = <<-SQL.squish
 CASE
    WHEN encounters.start IS NOT NULL THEN encounters.start
    ELSE encounters.created
 END
 #{order}
SQL

user.order(Arel.sql(order_statement))
```